# How can I disable hyperlinks in my Outlook signature?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, hyperlink, email-signature

I am using Outlook 2010 and I don't want my email address in my signature to be hyperlinked.

Is there a way to prevent that from happening?

Comment: Even if you remove the hyperlink, the email client of your recipients made add it back in as a convenience.

Comment: Remove it from the signature. If they get an email from you, they have your email address, right?

Answer (score 2):

Go to File tab => Options => Mail => Signatures

Enter your signature (including your email address, as per your requirement). Outlook will automatically create a hyperlink for your email address. To negate that, right-click on your hyper-linked email address and from the menu that pops up choose *"Remove hyperlink"*.

Answer (score 2):

This is plain and simple.

I'm assuming you don't want the appearance of where it will go blue when you send it to people, however before sending it, it looked normal and not hyperlinked.

The way i got around this and to make it so it appears as a not a hyperlink on both sides, sender and receiver.

Step 1: Open a new email.

Step 2: Go to signatures.

Step 3: click on yours.

Step 4: in the edit box, type your email and then press space. This should now of hyperlinked your email making it blue and underlined.

Step 5: you now want to highlight the whole email.

Step 6: Press underline twice, so the line disappears.

Step 7: Change the color of the font, to your desired color.

Step 8: Click save.

Now when you send your emails, it may still be a hyperlink, but it will not be blue or underlined on the receiver or senders side, keeping the same contract and colors you want.

hope this helps,

James

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful, but for grammar nuts, it going to be a hard sell.  The rule is:  two spaces after a comma, but...  if you don't want a hyperlink.

When I put an e-mail address or a website address in my signature I prefix the address with "e-mail:" or "website:", respectively, and to make it so no hyperlink is created I put no space in between the prefix and address:

Example:

> Name Lastname
>  Address 
>  Phone number 
>  e-mail:username@domain 
>  website:https://domain/dir/subdir/index.html

Superuser.com is formatting my url here, but MS Outlook does not do this.